# Partition-free subsets of $2^{[n]}$

Tags: co.combinatorics

Let $[n]$ denote the set of integers $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. A subset of $2^{[n]}$ is **partition-free** if it does not contain a partition of $[n]$.

> What is the maximum size of a partition-free subset of $2^{[n]}$?

Note that it is easy to get such a subset of size $2^{n-1}$: for some choice $x\in[n]$, we have a partition-free subset $\{S : S\in 2^{[n]},\ x\notin S\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a set $S$ and its complement, you can use at most one, so you can't do better than $2^{n-1}$.

Comment: So the next question is to characterize the examples of maximal size.

Comment: Well, they have to contain $\emptyset$. I just asked a question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/154321 which might be relevant.